# Building Qt on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt4, windows-7-x64

Was anyone able to build Qt on Windows 7 (64-bit) with Visual Studio 2010? I've tried different compilers and the `-no-webkit` option for configure, but every time nmake fails with error code U1077. Would be very greatful for suggestions.

Comment: Which bit of QT are you building? Do you have download link please?

Comment: Qt 4.6.2, the complete sdk. The download link - http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/sdk-windows-cpp

Comment: It looks like I was just able to build it using Ben's hint for configure options:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644172/building-qt-4-5-with-visual-c-2010

Answer (score 3):

I successfully compiled 64-bit version of Qt 4.7.2 (minimal) on Windows 7 64-bit (Ultimate) with VS2010 SP1 + Windows SDK 7.1 (64-bit release environment).
Installation order was as recommended:
1. Visual Studio 2010
2. Windows SDK 7.1
3. Visual Studio 2010 SP1
4. Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Compiler Update for the Windows SDK 7.1
VS2010 have been switched to use Windows SDK 7.1 as a default Platform Toolset:
`"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Setup\WindowsSdkVer.exe" -version:v7.1`
OpenSSL 64-bit version have been compiled as described here:
http://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_Desktop_for_Windows_with_MSVC#Building_OpenSSL
and here:
http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#W64
OpenSSL 64-bit version installation path was:
"C:\Program Files\OpenSSL"
Content of qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.2.zip have been unpacked here:
"C:\Program Files\Nokia\Qt 4.7.2"
To configure build environment I used batch script (setqtbuildenv.cmd) with the following content:
`@echo off

echo Setting Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 Environment
set WINSDKDIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1
call "%WINSDKDIR%\Bin\SetEnv.cmd" /Release /x64 /win7

echo Setting OpenSSL Environment
set OPENSSLDIR=C:\PROGRA~1\OpenSSL
set PATH=%OPENSSLDIR%\bin;%PATH%
set LIB=%OPENSSLDIR%\lib;%LIB%
set INCLUDE=%OPENSSLDIR%\include;%INCLUDE%

echo Setting Qt Environment
set QTDIR=C:\PROGRA~1\Nokia\QT47~1.2
set PATH=%PATH%;%QTDIR%\bin

cd /d "%QTDIR%"

configure.exe -release -opensource -shared -platform win32-msvc2010 -no-webkit -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-script -no-scripttools -no-qt3support -no-multimedia -no-ltcg`
And finally nmake command have been used.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue , ultimately gave up building from source and used the binary instead. Works fine so far (since i am only using it for my graphics course project)