# Qt 4.7.1, Qt Creator and VS 2010 installation problems

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, qt-creator

On my computer (Win7 32, VS2010 Ultimate) I would like to use Qt Creator and Qt Visual Studio add in, both LGPL versions.

There are minGW and VS2008 versions of Qt frameworks on the Nokia websites, I did not find VS 2010 version.

So I have installed Qt 2010.05 SDK and in the VS 2010 Command prompt the following steps have been performed:

```
configure -static
nmake sub-src
```

I checked Qt Creator and it successfully runs. After the translation has been finished I installed VS 2010 add I tried to add new Qt version int the path

```
C:\Qt\2010.05\qt
```

But the following error message has been appeared:

*Qt in the given path was built using minGW*

It do not understand why because the translation has been performed for the VS2010.

Where is the error? How to install it correctly?

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you find a way to solve it yet?

Answer (score 5):

I found out from a German Qt forum that, VS add-in looks for `libqtmain.a` and `libqtmaind.a` files to determine if it is built with MinGW. Guess what? Qt ships with those files.

Delete them, and you will be fine.

Comment: this worked great! instead of deleting the files, I renamed them to VS2005_COMPATIBILITY_libqtmain.a and VS2005_COMPATIBILITY_libqtmaind.a

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, The Vs2008 version works fine with VS2010. I didn't need to build it or anything. You can install that and then just run the latest version of the VS plug-in installer and you should see the Qt menu options in VS2010.

AFAIR your command line is incomplete: I remember one had to specify the build platform. It could be that it's using mingw to build Qt since you didn't specify the VS version in the parameters. The following post might be of interest to you: [Building Qt 4.5 with Visual C++ 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644172/building-qt-4-5-with-visual-c-2010)

Comment: While performing development tasks, it works with the version for VS2008. But I faced problems with manifests dependencies when compiling my code with Visual Studio 2010 and using it on other machines, with no dev tools installed. It is even funnier in case the user running the app is not even an administrator on that machine.

Comment: Thanks for the info, good to know! I just recently installed everything and haven't deployed yet as we are still in the early development phase.

Comment: So what is the conclusion on this? Do we need to compile Qt from source for using it with VS2010, or not? I am struggling in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585195/how-to-build-a-hello-word-like-application-using-qt-and-vs2010/5585402#5585402

Comment: Ralf, I think you are incorrect on this. You must also have VS2008 installed on your machine, because for everyone else it fails because we are missing VS2008 (VC90) debug CRT.

Comment: @Matt: thanks for the info which concurs with Cătălin Pitiș' comment. FWIW we also ended up building Qt as described in zsero's post and that works well for us.