# how to build a hello word like application using Qt and VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, qt, build

I have read many answers both here and on other places on the net, but I'm still unable to build / run a small hello world like application using VS2010 and the latest Qt opensource (4.7.2) for VS2008.

Here are the steps I've done, and of course restarted where needed:

1. installed VS2010
2. installed VS2010 SP1
3. downloaded and installed qt-win-opensource-4.7.2-vs2008.exe
4. downloaded and installed qt-vs-addin-1.1.9.exe

In VS2010 now I have the project templates for Qt. I selected QT Application, accepted defaults and created one. First it didn't find the QTDIR folder. So I've run c:\Qt\4.7.2\bin\qtvars.bat as administrator, and now VS2010 have no problem with building the project / finding the include files.

And thats where my knowledge stopped, I still cannot run the exe files created from the build. When starting the created exe files from Total Commander, it says:

[image: problem2]

and when starting them from within VS2010 it says:
[image: problem]

Can you help me what is causing this problem and what is a possible solution for this? **Is all this happening because Qt is compiled for VS2008 and I'm trying to use VS2010?** But I've read it on many places that it should work well.

**And if I need to recompile Qt for VS2010, then what is the best way to do it?** I would like to create minimalistic OpenGL applications using Qt, what is the appropriate way to configure Qt in this case?

**Shell I uninstall Qt totally and start from sources?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of reading and trial and error, I made it work and I wrote a guide about it here:

[How to build Qt for Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601950/how-to-build-qt-for-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have downloaded the source. You can either [build the SDK](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/install-win.html) using the downloaded source or you can download an installable SDK: http://get.qt.nokia.com/qt/source/qt-win-opensource-4.7.2-vs2008.exe. This installs just the framework. You have to download the development tools (QtCreator, QtDesigner, QtAssistant, etc) separately.

Comment: Are you sure what you've said is right? Your comment helped me, but I think its incorrect. I have downloaded the built version, which is not working in VS2008. I have to download the source version, which after a long compiling will work correctly in VS2010. The newest source is in an archive called: qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.2.zip That archive is what I needed.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The link to the exe I gave in the answer is built for Windows but using Mingw. Here is the one that works with VS2008: http://get.qt.nokia.com/qt/source/qt-win-opensource-4.7.2-vs2008.exe. Updated the answer as well.

Comment: This is what I used, and what produced errors (look in the question, in point 3.) I think this is what is **not working** with VS2010. I think the only option with VS2010 is to build from source.

Comment: see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275050/qt-4-7-1-qt-creator-and-vs-2010-installation-problems